# I set CONN_MAX_AGE as 60 in my django app, but the database link still exist after 60 seconds, why?

Tags: mysql, django

I set CONN_MAX_AGE as 60 in my django app, but the database link  still exist after 60 seconds, why?
here is the setting:

```
   DATABASES = {
      'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
           'NAME': 'craw',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
           'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
           'PASSWORD': 'root',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
           'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
            'CONN_MAX_AGE':60
            }
   }
```

here is the mysql connections:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your extra options in `OPTIONS`, as detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database):

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'craw',
       'USER': 'root',
       'PASSWORD': 'root',
       'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
       'PORT': '3306',
       'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,
  }
}
```

Comment: my django version is 1.6.5. so you mean it still work for your answer?

Comment: when I set `'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60` like you said, I run  my django app, I got this error:`TypeError('keywords must be strings',)`. My django app is a mutithread app.

Comment: Change `60` to `'60'`

Comment: set CONN_MAX_AGE to a positive number of seconds. Doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#persistent-connections

Comment: This wasn't even correct for the linked-to Django 1.7. `CONN_MAX_AGE` should not be within `OPTIONS`, but should be at the same level as `ENGINE`, `NAME`, etc. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-CONN_MAX_AGE